# java call hive in tomcat :: permission deny

Tags: java, tomcat, hive

I want to provide a hiveClient.jar to do hive SQL. The code as follows

```
public class HiveClient {
    private String sql;

    public HiveClient(String sql) {
        this.sql = sql; 
    }

    public int procedure(){
        String[] command = {"hive", "-e", sql};
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        ...
        do something with process...
    }
```

}

I will input the sql and get output from process.getInputStream().

The problem is when I call this jar in linux shell, everything is OK

```
java -cp .:./hiveClient.jar HiveMain
```

But when I put this jar in tomcat lib folder, and call this object, the will be permission deny ERROR. However, the hive user and tomcat user both are 'admin'.

```
HiveClient hc = new HiveClient(parameters.toString());
int returnCode = hc.procedure();

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hive": error=13, permission deny
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
at com.jd.ads.data.hiveClient.HiveClient.execute(HiveClient.java:89)
at com.jd.ads.data.hiveClient.HiveClient.procedure(HiveClient.java:146)
at com.jd.ad.data.download.handler.InvokeHiveHandler.read(InvokeHiveHandler.java:78)
at com.jd.ad.data.download.handler.AbstractRunableHandler.run(AbstractRunableHandler.java:61)
at com.jd.ad.data.download.pipeline.DefaultPipeLine.run(DefaultPipeLine.java:103)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, permission deny
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
... 10 more
```

I want to know how can I call "hive -e " in tomcat, think you very much!

Comment: try changing this line  String[] command = {"hive", "-e", sql}; to  String[] command = {"sudo hive", "-e", sql};

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have super user permission :(

Comment: that is why sudo should do

Comment: I want to say that , I don't have sodu password... But I can execute hive in shell

Comment: oh mea culpa ! sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason is I didn't set environment variables in tomcat. Just add follows into server/bin/start.sh

```
export PATH=/export/jdhive-2.0.0-HADOOP-2.7.1/bin:/export/hadoop-2.7.1-admin/bin:/export/hadoop-2.7.1-admin/sbin:/export/hadoop-2.7.1-admin/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/export/servers/jdk1.7.0_71/bin:$PATH
export HIVE_HOME=/export/jdhive-2.0.0-HADOOP-2.7.1
export UDF_PATH=$HIVE_HOME/udf
```